# list of Data to String

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

So I have a list of Data, I know newtype is currently better but I will add more things to it. I would like to convert a list of Pack to a String.

```
unpack [Pack ('a','b'), Pack ('c','d') , Pack (' ', 'e') ] = "abcd e"
```

I was thinking about using a foldl but am stuck trying to figure it out.

```
data Pack= Pack (Char, Char) deriving ( Show)
unPack:: [Pack] -> String

unpack list = foldr (\Pack (a,b) -> show a + show b -> concat) "" list
```

Thx for the helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Pack` type is isomorphic to two-character strings:

```
pack2String :: Pack -> String
pack2String (Pack (a,b)) = a:[b]

string2Pack :: String -> Pack   -- partial, since String isn't limited in length
string2Pack (a:[b]) = Pack (a, b)
```

(Note that `Pack (a,b)` already adds an unnecessary level of wrapping; `data Pack  = Pack Char Char` is also isomorphic to `Pack (Char, Char)`.)

As such, you don't actually need `foldr`; you can use the list monad instead.

```
unpack :: [Pack] -> String
unpack xs = xs >>= pack2String
```

If you aren't yet comfortable with monads, you can just use the `concatMap` function directly:

```
unpack :: [Pack] -> String
unpack = concatMap pack2String
```

Comment: `unpack xs = xs >>= pack2String` would make more sense to me as the list monad example.

Comment: @4castle I'll comment later if I can think of a good excuse for not saying that in the first place :) (Right now, I'll blame lack of coffee and/or good breakfast.)

Answer (score 4):

To pattern-patch on `Pack xyz` in a lambda, you need to put it in parentheses:

```
            foldr (\(Pack (a,b)) -> ...)
```

What you wrote would actually parse as two separate arguments

```
            foldr (\(Pack) -> \(a,b) -> ...)
```

Next, you can't concatenate strings with `+`, that's for numbers. `++` or `<>` are for lists / strings.

Then, the `-> concat` isn't valid syntax. What you want to do is concatenate the remainder of the foldr computation to the shown `a` and `b`. That remainder is the second argument of the folding function:

```
            foldr (\(Pack (a,b)) rest -> show a ++ show b ++ rest)
```

...or shorter,

```
            foldr (\(Pack (a,b)) -> shows a . shows b)
```